# no sound with web audio api

Tags: web-audio-api

I was experimenting the Web Audio API

with

```
var context = new webkitAudioContext();
//alert(context);
//alert(context.createOscillator);
var oscillator = context.createOscillator(); 

oscillator.connect(context.destination);
oscillator.noteOn(0);
```

but I get no sound, so I was wondering what I missing

the alert(context) that is commented out prints [object AudioContext]
but the following alert prints undefined

and when i try alert(context.decodeAudioData) its prints that is a function

thank you for the help

Comment: Hmm... this code works fine for me. Can you clarify which statement in your snippet prints "undefined"?  Is it `alert(context)` or `alert(context.createOscillator())`?

Comment: alert(context.createOscillator); without () returns undefined

Comment: What browser are you using?  Are you sure it supports the Web Audio API?  Here's a list of the ones that do: http://caniuse.com/audio-api

Comment: thanks. I installed another version and it worked. I thought if new webkitAudioContext() existed the rest also worked, so I didnt even considered it

Comment: Cool. Glad you sorted it out. :)

Answer (score -1):

Your problem here is the AudioContext differs between browser. For a fixed version see [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vAPYu/1/).

```
try {
    if (! window.AudioContext) {
        if (! window.webkitAudioContext) {
            bad_browser();
            return;
        }
        window.AudioContext = window.webkitAudioContext;
    }

    context = new AudioContext();
}
catch(e) {
    console.log('Web Audio API is not supported in this browser');
}

var oscillator = context.createOscillator(); 

oscillator.connect(context.destination);
oscillator.noteOn(0);
```

Comment: `oscillator.noteOn is not a function`

Comment: Haven't tested it but I believe `oscillator.start()` should work these days.